# Adding to the back a a linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to add on element to the back of a linked list. I try to do so by iterating over the list untill I encouter a pointer to 0. Than I make a new pointer that points to this one and I try to let it point towards a new Node of my list. The compiler has no remarks, but when I try to write down my list it does not include the element I tried to add.

```
void add_back(Node * s, int x) {
    Node * new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node * start = s;
    new_node->value = x;
    new_node->next = 0;
    while(start != 0) {
        start = start->next;
    }
    Node ** plaats = &start;
    *plaats = new_node;
}
```

The used struct:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node * next;
};
typedef struct Node Node;
```

Comment: `Node ** plaats = &start;` : `&start` is address of local variable `start`. `*plaats = new_node;` meant `Node * start = new_node;`

Comment: If you are creating a linked list, I would recommend using a sentry node, this way there is no special cases for empty list, last element etc. example here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5d9d9405a9feb58f1577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can change the head of the list when the list is empty. So you have to pass the head by reference.

Thus the function will look the following way

```
void add_back( Node **head, int x ) 
{
    Node **tail = head;
    Node *new_node;

    while ( *tail != NULL ) tail = &( *tail )->next;

    new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    new_node->value = x;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    *tail = new_node;
}
```

So if you will define your list like

```
Node *head = NULL;
```

then the function is called like

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; i < 10; i++ ) add_back( &head, i );
```

Answer (score 3):

You did the hard part - this is all you need to do in the last few lines.

```
void add_back(Node * s, int x) {

    if(s == NULL)  // handle empty list
            return;

    Node * new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->value = x;
    Node * start = s;
    while(start->next != NULL) { //reach the last node - don't traverse further
        start = start->next;
    }
    new_node->next = NULL;
    start->next = newnode;

    /* not required
    Node ** plaats = &start;
   *plaats = new_node;
    */
}
```

This:

```
    while(start->next != 0) { //reach the last node - don't traverse further
        start = start->next;
    }
```

Makes you reach here:

```
 +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
 |    |     +-->|     |     +-->|     | NULL |
 +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
                                /
                            LastNode
```

These 2 lines:

```
    new_node->next = 0;
    start->next = newnode;
```

Do this:

```
 +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+           +-----+------+
 |    |     +-->|     |     +-->|     |    ------------->|     | NULL |
 +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+           +-----+------+
                                                          /
                                                       New Node
```

Comment: assuming that "add_back" gets a list of at least one element, else start->next crashes.

Comment: return on enmoty list?  that'll make for intersting bugs! better to die with some embarassing error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the loop to find the last node, when the loop is over `start` is not the last node, it's `NULL`. You then get the address of `start`, which will give you a pointer to the *local* variable `start` and assign the new node to that place.

Instead have a specific check if the list is empty, then add the node as the first node. If the list is not empty, loop while `start->next` is not `NULL`, and make `start->next` point to the new node.

Answer (score 0):

additionally, I would suggest to enhance the function add_back() to get a POINTER to a node-list-head, and check, whether the head is empty and result a new head, else do the suggested solutions

```
Node *add(Node **s, int x)
{
  Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  ... fill n;
  n->next = NULL;

  /* no head parameter */
  if (s == NULL) {
    return n;
  }

  /* empty head */
  if (*s == NULL) {
    *s = n;
  } else {
  /* append to end */
     ... code from other solution with (*s) instead of s
  }

  return *s;
}


...
Node *head = NULL;
add(&head, 1);
...
```

by returning the maybe-new head, you can use add() as a function and use the result right away

```
head = NULL; 
printnodelist(add(&head, 1));
iterateovernodelist(head);
```

Comment: of course you must set `n->value` and `n->next` in case of an empty list too ... and is you return the list head the double pointer is not really necessary as you could have the original parameter type `Node *s` and call `head = add( head, 1 );`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt nope, you would loose 'head', if you have something like 'head = NULL; printnodelist(add(head, 1));' head is still NULL. in my case, 'head = NULL; printnodelist(add(&head, 1));' head point to the list

Comment: well, `printnodelist(head=add(head,1))` would work and also an initialization like `Node *head = add(NULL,42);` would be possible. I think that's just a matter of taste.

Comment: okay, i am coming from functional programming, so doing assignments especially inside parameter-paranteses is the ugliest thing one can do. But I changed my function to your NULL-case

Answer (score 0):

```
 void add_back(Node * s, int x) {
```

that's wrong for a start. with that prototype you can't add to an empty list.

Comment: depends on the definition. his definition is: adding to a back of a list, so there should be a list to use this function.

Comment: @Peter Miehle You are wrong. In general case he can use the function for empty lists that have head equal to NULL.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - Question is fairly clear for me - OP is not trying to add to empty list. The list has been created understood by the OP's statement `I'm trying to add on element to the back of a linked list.`

Comment: @al-Acme I do not understand why did you make such a conclusion from the cited quote. Even if you would be right the function in any case shall be written correctly and be able to add a new node to an empty list.